# OpenLayers 4 get style from GeoJSON not find

Tags: openlayers, geojson

We created an API that returns a GeoJSON in accordance with this [styling guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Geojson_CSS) but then OpenLayers doesn't find the `style` key once I want to style each feature, here my code

```
var appLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: appSource,
  style: function (feature, resolution) {
    console.log(feature.getProperties()) // <== all geojson properties
     return [new ol.style.Style({
       fill: new ol.style.Fill({
         color: feature.get('...')
       }),
       stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
         color: feature.get('...'),
         width: feature.get('...')
       })
    })]
  }
})
```

and here my [GeoJSON file](https://www.traffwebdev.uk/tro/v1/restrictions?epsg=&x=523005.5999999999&y=177977.6&area=&radius=10&output=)

What I'm doing is creating a Vector layer and then add the features from the GeoJSON as features.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.traffwebdev.uk/tro/v1/restrictions?epsg=&x=383666+&y=398197&area=&radius=50&output=',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    // reads and converts GeoJSon to Feature Object
    var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(data, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:27700'
    })
    appSource.addFeatures(features)
  }
}).then(() => appLayer.getSource().refresh())
```

Comment: That extension to the GeoJSON standard isn't supported by OpenLayers.  All non-standard properties should be inside the properties object.

Comment: Ok, so in a standard GeoJSON file you can have just `type: id: properties geometry`?

Comment: `type`, `geometry` and `properties` are required, `id` is optional https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.2